# Is this good VB.Net coding syntax?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I need to check whether the two textboxes textbox_price and textbox_quantity contain numeric values or no values at all and if, give out the specific error message. textbox_item is only allowed non-numeric characters. Currently using the below concatenation of OR and it works, but I was wondering whether this was efficient and good. As you can see the check is long and difficult to read. Help appreciated.

```
If textbox_item.Text = "" Or textbox_price.Text = "" Or textbox_quantity.Text = "" Or          IsNumeric(textbox_price.Text) = False Or IsNumeric(textbox_quantity.Text) = False Or IsNumeric(textbox_item.Text) = True Then
        MsgBox("Please fill out every textbox with valid data", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Invalid entry")
        textbox_price.Text = ""
        textbox_item.Text = ""
        textbox_quantity.Text = ""
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Comment: Why would you want to wipe out any information they had already entered, just because they haven't entered *all* of it yet?

Comment: If it's winforms there are a built in validation system: http://www.sellsbrothers.com/writing/winformsdatavalidation.htm

Comment: There's a validation system for WPF to.

Comment: The compiler will tell you if its syntatically correct. It can't tell you if its functionally correct and isn't concerned with evaluating human readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer to see a long If..Then..ElseIf chain, so the error message can be specific to the problem.

```
If textbox_Item.Text = "" Then
    msgbox(errmsg1)
Elseif Not IsNumberic(textbox_Item.Text) Then
    msgbox(errmsg2)
Elseif ....
```

Comment: But if you leave it as one long IF, use ORELSE like Taylor said.

Comment: `Elseif` smells, IMO, its like nesting but with just the mental eyesore.

Comment: Yeah, if you plan to have slightly different responses based on which Textbox isn't properly filled out, you should definitely go with this approach.

Comment: Yes I chose the ElseIf approach. It works as intended and is also easier to read. Thanks for all your responses.

Answer (score 2):

Looking only at the logic for the `If...Then` statement (and not the code you wish to execute), I would change it to this:

```
If textbox_item.Text = "" OrElse textbox_price.Text = "" OrElse textbox_quantity.Text = "" OrElse _
    IsNumeric(textbox_price.Text) = False OrElse IsNumeric(textbox_quantity.Text) = False OrElse IsNumeric(textbox_item.Text) = True Then
    'Code to execute goes here
End If
```

Basically, change the `Or` to `OrElse` in each case.  That way, as soon as one of the conditions is satisfied, the other ones are not checked.

Here's a short article explaining `OrElse` in VB .NET:

[MSDN - OrElse Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea1sssb2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check what the implementation of IsNumeric is doing under the covers. I also question what you are doing after your If block. If you are planning on consuming the value after the check, it might be best to just use Decimal.TryParse (or which ever numeric tryparse you want to use) and send the validation prompt in the else clause:

```
Dim price As Decimal
Dim quantity As Integer
Dim item as As Double

If Decimal.TryParse(textbox_price.text, price) 
   AndAlso Integer.TryParse(textbox_quantity.Text, quantity)
   AndAlso Double.TryParse(textbox_item.Text, item) Then
   '' Do something with the values
Else
   '' Send validation prompt
End If
```

The advantage of this option is you aren't parsing the value twice (IsNumeric and TryParse). As I recall, IsNumeric attempts the parse, but just throws the result away. If you want the result, use TryParse. TryParse also handles null and empty strings, so you don't need those tests explicitly yourself either.